# Set pagenumber on specific position

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Im creating an pdf and want to set the pagenumber of each page manually. The problem is, that the pagenumber should be at a specific position on the page and the number should be rotate 90 degrees.

Can you help me with this one?

Kr,

Sensewell

Comment: When you say you *"want to set the pagenumber of each page manually"*, do you mean the page number Adobe Reader shows in its control elements or do you mean the page number drawn in the page content of the displayed PDF? And which iText version do you mean, 5.5.x or 7.0.x? And for which platform, Java, .Net, Android?

Comment: hi. the idea is to set the physical number of each page with itext- like the one which always appears in books in the right corner. I am using 5.5.x under java- sorry for not mention this.

Comment: Have you looked at the example [TextFooter.java](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events/page-events-headers-and-footers#692-textfooter.java) on the developers.itextpdf.com?  To rotate the text written, simply change the final parameter of the respective `ColumnText.showTextAligned` to the desired angle. The current page number can be retrieved as `writer.getPageNumber()`.